# Chrome Developer Console shortcut CTRL Shift J does nothing

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I'm trying to write an AHK bot that fills in input boxes in a Webapp so I need to be able to open the Developer Tools > Console with a simple shortcut.

The shortcut that says it should open Console doesn't do anything(CTRL + Shift + J). However if I use the Right Shift + Right Control + J it does open the Elements tab, but that's not what I meant to open, the Console tab inside Chrome Dev Tools.

https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/shortcuts

Any tips?
My keyboard layout is Icelandic. Need the bot to be able to launch in that layout and any other layout for that matter.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by pressing F12 then the ESC (escape) key, that brings up the Console.

Not sure why the Chrome developer blog doesn't list the right shortcut though.

Answer (score 0):

Even for me <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> is not working.
<kbd>F12</kbd> is equivalent to <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>   Open whatever panel you used last

Answer (score 0):

No, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> takes an instant GIF of me struggling to open the javascript console.

Edit: Real answer: Press <kbd>F12</kbd> to open the console. OR, press the "⁝" button, hover over "More Tools ‣" and click "Developer Tools <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>". These open the HTML panel, but to get to the console, press "Console". I know there are two "Console" buttons, but any of them works.

Comment: I found this old answer shortly after getting that privilege